# How to spy on a method that receives function arguments?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

if I have a function:

```
function X() {
  some.external.library.method('X');
}
```

then I can test it (I'm using mocha + sinon) where I spy on the external library method like this:

```
var spy = sinon.spy(some.external.library, 'method');
X();
spy.calledWith('X');
```

...but what if the implementation passes an internally defined function to the method I'm spying on?

```
function X() {
  function INTERNAL() { ... }
  some.external.library.method(INTERNAL)
}
```

how do I test for it?

```
spy.calledWith(...?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assert an `actual` object without having the access to the `expected` object. If you don't know what the private function is - you simply can't compare if it's the same thing or not - you'll need to make it public.

However, I think you should consider testing that the callback actually does the stuff you expect it to do. Why do you even care *which* function was passed as an argument? As long as the function provides desired side effects - you're OK. Checking for `calledWith` is likely testing the implementation details - not behavior, which itself is likely a bad practice.

You're using a spy, not a stub - which means that your `method` actually runs - does it call the function? If it does - you can check the results. If it doesn't - you can access that function in a number of ways: `spy.firstCall.args[0]` / `spy.getCall(0).args[0]`. If it were a stub, you could configure it to callback automatically, like so: `stub.yields(someValue)` - this will call the last argument (your `INTERNAL` function) with `someValue`.